# Not receiving UITextField messages

Tags: iphone

I need to do some processing after my user leaves a text field.

I thought I had turned on notification by doing this:

```
@interface CreditCardAppViewController : UIViewController 
       <UITextFieldDelegate> {
```

However, my events are not getting fired. I don't know why?

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

NSLog(@"This never gets called, Why?");


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the text field's delegate. If you created the text field in code, then something like `[myTextField setDelegate:self];`

or if you created the text field in Interface Builder, control + click + drag from the text field to your view controller instance, and select delegate.

Without setting the delegate, the delegate messages will never be sent to your controller.